# how to use ruby code after its written, is it standalone or need to be in a web application?

Tags: ruby, web

Confused a little on ruby. I know it makes `.rb` files, but does it make exe or com files or is it just used as as web application?

I know a bit writing the code, but what to do with the files after.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just run the .rb file in the shell or command prompt. For example in the windows command prompt:

```
C:\path\> ruby filename.rb
```

This will execute the filename.rb file from the command prompt.

If you need to run a ruby program on a computer without a ruby installation there are a few options out there.

Try this website: 
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/packaging_to_executables

I personally have used OCRA to pass a program to relatives who are less computer literate. It was pretty straight forward,I haven't tried the other tools.

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

the question is a bit too broad.

you have to step back and look at how source code in general ends up being executed (i.e. it is used).

In case of some programming languages (e.g. C/C++) it's compiled to a native form and can be executed directly afterwards;

In case of other languages it's compiled to an intermediate form (e.g. Java/C#) and executed by a vm (jvm/clr)

In case of yet other languages is interpreted at runtime (e.g. Ruby/Python).

So in the specific case of Ruby, you have the interpreter that loads the rb files and runs them. This can be in the context of standalone apps or in th e context of a web server, but you almost always have the interpreter making sense of the ruby files. you don't get an executable the same way as the you get for languages that are compiled to machine code.

Comment: then what is a practical use for ruby?

Comment: the language is very expressive and it's faster/easier to develop in it than it is to develop in C/C++/etc. In most cases it's not a big deal to have the interpreter on the machine.